# How do I pass a variable in an onclick event?

Tags: php, html

In a PHP page, I need to open a URL when a button or link is clicked. But the URL that I open needs a variable.

Background - when the user presses the "proceed" button, a page that depends on the price will open.  Different prices, different page.

I hope I'm not too obtuse, but here's a text example.
I have an order confirmation page that includes the price in the URL:
`www.xys.com/confirm?price=100`

The confirm page is where the user gets to proceed or stop. Two buttons.
The price determines which page we open when the user clicks on "proceed".

So, if the price is `$100`, the user sees `page_100.php`.  If the price is `$200` the user sees `page_200.php`

The problem I am running into is that $price does not translate into a value

```
<?php
$price = $_GET['price'];
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='selector.php?$price';return false;" name="" value="Proceed">
?>
```

What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: What quotes are you using? ' or "

Comment: The code snippet you provided is not valid php.  You can't just paste html into the middle of a php block and have it work.  If that is your code, it is incorrect.

Comment: This could result in a cross-site scripting vulnerability. I suggest you filter your $_GET variables before echoing them into the document.

Comment: Your not getting a server error with `<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='selector.php?$price';return false;" name="" value="Proceed">` in your `PHP` block?

Comment: @Fred-ii, The marked duplicate is not at stake here. There is a plain syntax error here. The double or single quotes are *not* the problem.

Comment: then tell that other guy to delete his answer with the link for it @trincot plus it's up to the OP to tell me that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using this

```
$price = 10;
echo '<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href=\'selector.php?'.$price.'\';return false;" name="" value="Proceed">';
```

Comment: care to give an explanation here?

Comment: Thank you - I am still learning PHP and I tried everything I could, but for echo...  Works exactly as desired.

Comment: Fred, please unmark it as a duplicate or show me where the question was already answered.

Comment: @user3573562 I already did, like ... over 3 hours ago http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34233603/revisions the timestamp doesn't lie. *Post Reopened by trincot, Russ, Fred -ii- php  
occurred 3 hours ago* prior to my comment here.

Comment: *"Try using this"* answers are considered as very low quality answers and does NOT explain what the problem was (and what you did to fix their code) and will not serve future visitors to the question/answer with less knowledge in order to learn.

Comment: Fred. The problem was, apparently, that I was using the variable inside a quoted string. Dipesh led me to the correct solution of taking the variables outside of the quotes.

As a newbie to PHP I was confused because 
echo "this is a string with a $var in it"; does expand the variable.